# Symfony 4 FOSRestBundle serializing with JMSSerializer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, fosrestbundle, jms-serializer

I am building API with Symfony 4 and FOSRestBundle. I have pretty basic relations:

Entity: **User.php**

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
*/
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @JMS\Groups({"onlyId"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(unique=true, type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserProduct", mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $userProducts;
```

Entity: **UserProduct.php**

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserProductRepository")
*/
class UserProduct
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @JMS\Groups({"onlyId"})
     */
    private $id;

    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="userProducts")
     * @JMS\Groups({"onlyId"})
     */
    private $user;
```

Config: **fos_rest.yaml**

```
fos_rest:
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
#    param_fetcher_listener:  true
#    allowed_methods_listener:  true
#    routing_loader: true
#    view:
#        view_response_listener:  true
#    exception:
#        codes:
#            App\Exception\MyException: 403
#        messages:
#            App\Exception\MyException: Forbidden area.
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/api, prefer_extension: true, fallback_format: json, priorities: [ json, html ] }
            - { path: ^/login_check, stop: true }
            - { path: ^/register, stop: true }
```

At first, I couldn't **POST** UserProduct sending JSON to the endpoint when I was posting user ID along with JSON data as it was throwing that it expects an instance of `entity`, not `integer` or whatever I was sending. I figured that out with this tutorial -> https://medium.com/@maartendeboer/using-the-symfony-serializer-with-doctrine-relations-69ecb17e6ebd

it uses Symfony Serializer. What I got was `circular reference` error when returning `View` of FOSRestBundle. In this point I knew that `circular reference` errors are handled fine with JMS Serializer tool and used it inside my `postUserProductAction` controller:

To **POST** a product and handle the `circular reference` I use this controller (deserializing posted JSON with custom written deserialize method from the tutorial, insterting it to the database and then returning the **Response** (not View) with help of JMS Serializer and it's Groups):

```
class UserProductController extends FOSRestController
    {
    /**
     * @Rest\Route("/api/product", name="userProduct")
     *
     *
     * @Method("POST")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param SerializerInterface $serializer
     * @return Response
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function postUserProductAction(Request $request, SerializerInterface $serializer): View
    {
        $userProduct = $serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), UserProduct::class, 'json');
        dump($userProduct);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($userProduct);
        $em->flush();

        $userProduct = $this->JMSSerializeWithGroups($userProduct,array('onlyId'));
        return new View($userProduct, Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}

    /**
     * @param $entity
     * @param array $groupArray
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function JMSSerializeWithGroups($entity, Array $groupArray)
    {
        $JMSserializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
        $entity = $JMSserializer->serialize( $entity, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups($groupArray));
        return $entity;
    }
```

Response I get is nice and clear:

```
{
    "id": 100,
    "user": {
        "id": 9
    }
}
```

But it seems like a lot of unnecessary steps. Also, if I choose this approach I need to add JMS serializing by myself to every of my controllers (GET, PUT etc).

So my **question would be** why do FOSRestBundle does not use JMS by default for rendering `View`, as it says it should in their documentation (if it is installed and registered)? Should I add it somewhere in addition for FOSRestBundle to recognize it? And maybe if it would, I wouldn't need to use Symfony Serializer at the first place? I think I may be lost in all Symfony 4 upgrades.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't get any suggestions, I stick with the same solution I posted. I'll leave it in case someone needs it as it's fully working example.

Cheers